# django editing model with fields from related model

Tags: django, django-forms

I've created this `UserProfile` model on my Django app where I want to store some user info such as `about_me`, `twitter` etc.

In my form I (now) just added extra fields from the user model (first name, last name, email) and after saving the user profile I query for the user model and update that one as well but I was wondering if I can load those fields from a separate form (the `UserForm`) on the same page without having to add those fields manually. Here's my code so far:

```
class ProfileForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    first_name = forms.CharField( required = True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'First name'
        }
    ) )

    last_name = forms.CharField( required = True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Last name'
        }
    ) )

    email = forms.EmailField( required = True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Email address'
        }
    ) )

    facebook_url = forms.URLField( required = False )
    gplus_url = forms.URLField( required = False )
    about_me = forms.CharField( required = False, widget = forms.Textarea( attrs = {
        'rows': 10,
        'placeholder': 'Something about you'
    } ) )

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['facebook_url', 'gplus_url', 'twitter_url', 'website', 'about_me']
        widgets = {
            'facebook_url': forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                    'placeholder': 'Your facebook url'
                }
            ),
            'gplus_url': forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                    'placeholder': 'Your google+ url'
                }
            )
        }
```

As you can see the first 3 fields should be part of a different form but how do I do about including them? My code works fine but I have a feeling there's a `Django` way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 forms on one page. Just choose different prefixes for the forms:

```
user_form = UserForm(prefix='user_form')
profile_form = UserForm(prefix='profile_form')
```

Just print them out in one html `<form>` tag:

```
<form>
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Just validate each one, and save:

```
if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
    user_form.save()
    profile_form.save()
```

EDIT: as Daniel Roseman pointed out, you might want to check `is_valid()` separately on each form so you will always see errors on both forms. Something like this:

```
user_valid = user_form.is_valid()
profile_valid = profile_form.is_valid()

if user_valid and profile_valid:
    user_form.save()
    profile_form.save()
```

Comment: Slight tweak: the is_valid() calls will shortcut if the first one fails, so profile_form errors will not be shown if there are user_form ones. Better to call them both separately, then check they are both True.